# How to create a dataset from a folder of images for text recognition in Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, jupyter

I am working on a text recognition system in Python that takes an image of a printed text, and outputs a text of the words in that image.

To prepare the training and testing dataset, I have a folder that contains 35 subfolders (a-z and 1-9). Each subfolder contains around 45 images (png files) of a letter/number (folder a contains 45 images of letter a) in different fonts. Like this ones: [image: Example of letter a]
[image: Example of letter a] [image: Example of letter a]

I want to turn all this folders into a dataset I can use in my train and test sets:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = dataset
```

I have already done this downloading datasets like the MNIST one, but I want to know how to do it from a dataset created by myself.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the format of X_train? A matrix? How many numbers per value? 1D (gray)? 4D (colours + alpha)? Basically, you just need to use a file reader to get pixels isnt it? You want help to iterate over your directories? To read files?

Comment: Yeah, X_train is a matrix. I tried to use glob to iterate over all the files but it just returns an empty array.